# Problema na licença SDK ao rodar projeto Cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova, sdk

Fui rodar um projeto *Android* com *Cordova* porém deu um erro de licença e não consigo resolver, estava funcionando normal até eu adicionar um plugin para *qrcode*.

> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>           FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>         A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>           [Android Support Repository].
>           Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>
> Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
>
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: voce deve ter um android SDK instalado ai, atualiza ele via command line, algo tipo `TUAPASTASDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager`

Comment: Não sei se te ajuda, mas eu estava com esse problema também, tive que instalar uma versão anterior do sdk(25), depois disso deu certo. consegui buildar no cordova.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro ocorre porque você não aceitou os termos de licença para utilizar o *Android SDK*

Para resolver basta re-instalar o `Android Support Repository` ou a versão do SDK que ele irá pedir para aceitar os termos novamente.

> **Atualização**

Você pode fazer também como está [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206708/60376) dada na pergunta: [Ajuda com react native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206703), como comentado pelo @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: >>> Ou ao invés de reinstalar se fizer isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206708/3635 ? (`sdkmanager --licenses`)