# Ajuda com react native

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, react-native

Galera estou com um erro chato ao instalar o react native:

```
~/MyApp $ react-native run-android
Scanning 555 folders for symlinks in /home/henrique/MyApp/node_modules (4ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
File /home/henrique/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 in /home/henrique/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 23 in /home/henrique/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 23 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 23".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1]
  Please install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.957 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Já tentei instalar Android SDK Platform 23, mas ainda nada...
Alguém já passou por isso? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Galera eu reiniciei, agora ta com esse erro: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crie um arquivo chamado `local.properties` e vá até a pasta `android` do seu projeto do **ReactNative**.

A extensão do arquivo deve ser `.properties`.
Coloque a seguinte **configuração** dentro do arquivo:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Geralmente o Sdk é instalado nesse caminho, verifique se está correto antes de o fazer.

Se você estiver utilizando o **Windows**, utilize `\\` para inserir o caminho.

Se você estiver utilizando o `Android Studio` ou já tiver utilizado ele, você pode ir na pasta de um projeto criado, copiar o `local.properties` e colar na pasta **Android** do seu projeto do **ReactNative**.

---

Se você se deparar com o erro abaixo

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1]

Você pode fazer o seguinte: vá no diretório do **Sdk**, o mesmo que foi definido em **local.properties** e abre a pasta `tools\bin`, copie o caminho do diretório, abra o `CMD` e faça o seguinte:

```
cd C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin

C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager --licenses
```

Vai aparecer algo assim:

> x of y SDK package licenses not accepted
>   Review licenses that have not been accepted? (y/n)

Digite **Y** e aperte **enter**. Prossiga digitando **Y** e apertando **enter** para aceitar as **licenças**.

Comment: Obrigado Luc. Mas agora ele voltou a dar o erro inicial: Failed to install the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1]
  Please install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

Comment: É porque o caminho do Sdk que você colocou não tem essas `build tools`.

Comment: Tenta ver em qual diretório tu baixou e instalou as APIs, pega o caminho e coloca no `local.properties`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Luc! Parece que agora já está quase lá, ele ainda esta dando uns erros de inconsistência de uns arquivos > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of th
e missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http:
//d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Comment: Resposta editada!

Comment: Pô, value Luc, deu certo. Quer dizer ainda ta com uns probleminhas. Mas o pior já passou hehe ^^. Já consegui resolver a questão das licenças, quer dizer resolvi vários erros que estavam ocorrendo graças a você, muito obrigado. Já estou conseguindo abrir a tela do app no cel, apesar de estar vermelha dando alguns erros, mas acho que deve ser mais simples do que os outros. Mais uma vez agradeço muito pela ajuda! Tudo de bom parceiro.

Comment: Por nada!... :)

Comment: @HenriqueNascimento se a resposta resolveu o seu problema por favor marque-a como correta.